# Setting collider in 3D map (blender file)

Tags: c++, collision-detection, 3d, maps, blender

New to gamedev and I also have no idea about 3D files but, I'll try to explain the best I can. We are using our own custom engine built in C++ with OpenGL (glm, gl3w, glfw, entityx)

We have a 3D map in a Blender file (.dae), We want to set the colliders for the hitboxes so the player can't step outside. My colleagues started doing it by hand, but it would take a tremendous amount of work none of us want to spend doing a trivial task.

We worked with the same map in 2D (doing the same game in 2D and 3D), and my colleagues used a program to do it visually and then importing a .tmx file (I don't really know how or what program). The question is, is there a way to do the same in 3D? They say Blender (used to create the map) does not provide the tools necessary, or they probably don't know how.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I explained something wrong, I'll gladly answer any questions.

Answer (score 1):

The program they used was probably tiled. It's a 2d tilemap editor and it supports 2d shapes.

If you don't want to create the colliders by hand, then create your own tool for it. It shouldn't be hard, it's literally just throwing together a renderer, a flying camera and a way to create colliders, then make the program save these into a file with a custom file format and process it in your game. [Just make sure you don't start focusing more on the program than on your game](https://xkcd.com/1319/).